# drupal 7: include javascript with rules

Tags: 7, rules

I have: drupal 7 - php module enabled - rules module enabled

On one of my rules I have the action: custom php code

when I enter `<?php echo 'test code'; ?>` it correctly shows the text

I want to include javascript, I've attempted:

```
<?php
    drupal_add_js('var google_conversion_id = 1003933475; var google_conversion_language = "en"; var google_conversion_format = "3"; var google_conversion_color = "ffffff"; var google_conversion_label = "IC5cCMXVqwcQo57b3gM"; var google_conversion_value = 0;', 'inline');
    drupal_add_js('http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'external');
?>
```

and

```
<?php 
echo '<script src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"> </script>';
?>
```

but when I view the source, there's nothing included. It's somehow stripped out or something.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

Thanks for your advice

Comment: What is your rule active condition ? & Which page you are trying to add js ?

Comment: event = Completing the checkout process, as said when I echo a simple text it does work, but when I try to include JS, it doesn't :(

Comment: What is the path user redirected to once check out is completed ? I mean in which page you would like to add javascript ?

Comment: I want to include the javascript on the page where the 'completed order message' is shown. the url is /checkout/2659/complete (2659 is the order id, so this is variable)

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is it egregiously sloppy that editing can't fix?  Does it show no effort?  Would it not benefit someone in the future who would like to do something similar?

Comment: I dont get this either, people just like to downvote I suppose :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hook init to check for the path and add JavaScript in custom module.

```
<?php

function yourmodule_init() {
  if (arg(0) == "checkout" && arg(2) == "complete" && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    drupal_add_js('var google_conversion_id = 1003933475; var google_conversion_language = "en"; var google_conversion_format = "3"; var google_conversion_color = "ffffff"; var google_conversion_label = "IC5cCMXVqwcQo57b3gM"; var google_conversion_value = 0;', 'inline');
    drupal_add_js('http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'external');
  }
}

?>
```

OR

You can edit template.php and add below code.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
     if (arg(0) == "checkout" && arg(2) == "complete" && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        drupal_add_js('var google_conversion_id = 1003933475; var google_conversion_language = "en"; var google_conversion_format = "3"; var google_conversion_color = "ffffff"; var google_conversion_label = "IC5cCMXVqwcQo57b3gM"; var google_conversion_value = 0;', 'inline');
        drupal_add_js('http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'external');
      }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick replies anil :) Can I put this php in the custom php field of rules, or should I make a custom module?

Comment: It should be in custom module... Alternative can be template.php... Let me give you alternative solution in couple of minutes...

Comment: sorry for the late reply, there were some server problems. Your solution works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use [JS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector).

> Allows administrators to inject JS into the page output based on
>   configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple JS tweaks without
>   modifying a site's official theme - for example, a 'nighttime' color
>   scheme could be added during certain hours. The JS is added using
>   Drupal's standard drupal_add_js() function and respects page caching,
>   etc.